# Facebook & Twitter authentication on mobile application + API

Tags: android, ios, facebook, authentication, windows-phone

I have a question concerning Facebook/Twitter authentication on mobile application when dealing with an API as the mobile application backend.

Currently, I'm developing an application on the 3 platforms Android, iOS and Windows Phone. These applications are linked to an API which handles basic authentication (sign up, sign in) and provide access to a remote database.

Now, I want to let my users to authenticate with their facebook or twitter account, but I don't really know what to implement on the applications, and what to develop on the API. Moreover, I want to keep my existing basic authentication feature in the case the user doesn't want to authenticate with his facebook account.

I've heard about omniauth and the facebook & twitter APIs, but this does not really answer what I have in mind.

First, I've thought to implement everything server-side. This way, the applications provide the API the email and password of the user's facebook account. The applications tell that these credentials should be use to authenticate through the facebook API and my API just does the job. However, if I have well understood the articles I've read, when we want to authenticate through facebook, we are redirected to the facebook website in order for the user to confirm that he confirm to grant access to his facebook account. This is not really convenient.

So, after reading this, I've thought that it would be better to handle authentication on the mobile apps: applications get the facebook access token, fetch information of the facebook profile and create an account with this data on my API. The problem here is that we don't have a password to create a valid account.

We only get a temporary access token when authenticating with facebook, so how do I create an account in my database with this information? How can I handle sign in with it? Should I store in database that the user account has been created with facebook data?

So, how to make facebook or twitter authentication in that case? What should I do on my applications and what am I expecting to do on the API?

Comment: _“This way, the applications provide the API the email and password of the user's facebook account.”_ – You’re not allowed to ask the user for their Facebook login credentials. If you want to use FB login, you have to implement their login flow – and that means using a browser/webview, or their Android SDK. Once you got the access token, you make an API request for their user details, and then you store what part of that data you think is needed for your application.

Comment: Moreover, if your app is encouraging users to provide their credentials to 3rd party services like Facebook or Twitter, you risk getting locked out of those services for good, as this is an extremely dangerous thing to ask from your users.